# vba how to read the values from the worksheet and stores them in a 2d array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm basically trying to see if this would be a valid way to turn values from the worksheet and store it in a 2 dimensional array of integers.

So far what I come up with is this code:

```
'Generate a random integer from cell A1 to J10

Sub numrange()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:J10")
    With r
      .Formula = "=randbetween(1,100)"
      .Copy
      .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
   End With

'Turn A1 to J10 into a 2d array of integers

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("A1:J10")

arr = Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2))
```

would appreciate any clarification or edits that could be made to make this a valid array

Comment: FWIW it is faster just to do `.Values = .Values` instead `copy paste special`

Comment: After that arr(10,10) is a double & is the value of J:10, what do you want to do differently?  If you specifically want int or non-variant you are going to need to loop and do it manually.

Comment: its' already ok. just avoid last statement `arr = Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2))`. And you could also avoid `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` inside `With r` block

Comment: Simply: arr = Range("A1:J10").Value

Comment: Yes, its a `Variant()`

Comment: @AlexK. Yes I want it specifically to be an int, so should I enter Do While arr = int ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have an array of *pure* `integer` values then you have to copy "cell by cell"

```
Sub numrange()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:J10")
    r.Formula = "=randbetween(1,100)"

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    arr = Range("A1:J10").Value
    ReDim arrint(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)) As Integer
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arrint(i, j) = arr(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a sharm man, I like the use ReDim made it much more easier!

Comment: Glad it helps. Good coding!